# I pass a NSDictionary, but the function get nil

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary

This is weird. I have a NSDictionary. I pass it to a method. The NSDictionary is filled, but the reciever get nil. What could be?

```
    [self.manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSDictionary *responseObject)
     {
         NSString *code = responseObject[kCODE];

         if ([code isEqualToString:rAPI_SUCCESS]) {
             fulfiller([[ResponseDataModel alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject]);
```

I put a breakpoint in the fullfiler line, then this is the value:

```
Printing description of responseObject:
{
    code = "API_SUCCESS";
    data =     {
        cliente =         {
            celular = ******;
            email = "test@****.com";
            nombre = test;
            "user_token" = ACDF*****4;
            "ver_celular" = 1;
        };
    };
    message = "The operation was successful";
    success = 1;
}
```

Now in the receiver:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    if (!nsDictionaryClass) nsDictionaryClass = [NSDictionary class];

Printing description of dictionary:
(NSDictionary *) dictionary = <variable not available>
```

(Self is a valid reference)

This is with Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) in debug mode.

Comment: Sometimes restarting of XCode helps. Or you compiled it as RELEASE.

Comment: What is the rest of your `initWithDictionary:` method? Try using `NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);` as the first line of `initWithDictionary:` and see if it's nil or empty.

Comment: Without looking at your code (which you don't really show us anyway) I can say with about 80% certainty that the dictionary was never created.

Comment: Is weird: I log with NSLog and see the dict, but not in the debugger (ie: in xcode)

Comment: What is `fulfiller()`? A compiler macro perhaps?

Comment: Is from promisekit (http://promisekit.org/)